# What is the best data access layer driver in python independent of database type?

Tags: python, database

could you tell me which is the best python driver independent of database platform similar to PDO in PHP or JDBC in Java. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I believe "best" it's a matter of your preferences. But I find the [SQLAlchemy](http://www.sqlalchemy.org/) Core convenient. They support quite some database dialects and offer a ORM layer that's optional to use. It's easy to swap database without making any code change (I'm running SQLite3 in-memory for my test suit but Oracle and Postgres in production). You also get connection pooling and other stuff for free.

Answer (score 0):

Python has a [ODBC driver](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ODBC) which might fit your needs, especially if you are already familiar with JDBC.
Furthermore, the python standard defines an [API](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/) for database modules, which might help somewhat to abstract from the actual database implementation as well (I can't really tell how many implementations adhere to this standard as I only ever worked with the sqlite module, but the standard claims 'most').
A third option is mentioned [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DatabaseInterfaces): using JDBC with Jython.
Which would be the best for you depends on what you actually want to achieve, but from your comparison with JDBC I would suspect the first option using the ODBC driver might be the best for you.